Relationship between predictive power and Sharpe ratio
Let's say I have an algorithm that can predict the future return of a single stock. The covariance between its prediction and the real return of a stock is $\rho$. Based on this predictor, I can construct an optimal portfolio with appropriate leverage that maximizes expected return over long-term.   Let's say $\rho$ is known during the construction of the portfolio.  With reasonable assumption, can we express the sharpe ratio of the portfolio $S_{max}$ in term of $\rho$?  I would expect $S_{max} \to \infty$ when $\rho=1$ since you can achieve the infinite return by maximizing the leverage to $\infty$ when you know the future.

What is the question exactly?

Hi: correlation doesn't give so much info as far as profitability because it says nothing about the size of the returns.  So, if you are trying to fiind a relation between the sharpe ratio and the correlation of the predicted return and actual return, I don't think it exists.
